# how to fix problem with console.log in express

Tags: node.js, express

my express server stopped performing console.log when processing requests

On such issues, it is usually recommended to app.use (express.static (srPath)) to announce before routing, this recommendation is respected.
I have a problem with statics, when I comment on this line, logging starts to work. I have no idea why this is happening
Express version: "^ 4.16.4" used all time
repo: https://gitlab.com/igor_borisch/react-redux-node-app

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var axios = require ('axios');
var app = express();
var srcPath = path.join(__dirname, './public');


app.use(express.static(srcPath));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(srcPath);
    res.sendFile('./index.html', {root: srcPath});
});


app.get('/get-currencies', (req,res) => {
    axios.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=RUB')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        });
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('app listen on port 3001'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows, the express supports intermediate handlers, the intermediate handler in the parameters of the callback function has 3 pfrfmeters: req, res, next. You don't need to define next, as i understand, express will automatically find next handler to the route you use and execute it.
it's very important to put first intermediate handler. i try to write something like:

```
app.use('/',(req,res,next) => {express.static(srcPath)})
```

but it does not work, maybe because express.static method is wrapper of external module serve-static

my example below works correctly

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var axios = require ('axios');
var app = express();
var srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');


app.get('/',(req,res,next) => { //here just add next parameter
    console.log('login');
    next();
})

app.use('/',express.static(srcPath));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/get-currencies', (req,res) => {
    console.log('alo')
     axios.get('http://yandex.ru/')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log('recieve response');
            res.send(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.send(error);
        });
    }
);


app.listen(3001, () => console.log('app listening on port 3001'));
```